# Ansible Variables registered with with_items, how to use this variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have such a scenario, I need to use two files `A.bin, B.bin`, first look in the `files` directory, if not found, download directly from a server

```
- name: Send A.bin and B.bin
  copy: src={{item}}.bin dest=/opt/
  register: is_exist
  failed_when: False
  with_items:
    - A
    - B

- name: Download from a server A.bin, B.bin
  shell: wget -P /opt/{{item.item}} {{base_url}}{{item.item}}.bin
  when: item.item.exception is defined
  with_items:
    - is_exist.results
```

But this will give an error:

```
The conditional check 'item.item.exception is defined' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.item.exception is defined): 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'item'
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest visually reviewing the structure of `is_exist` variable.

```
- debug: msg="{{ is_exist }}"
```

Then, if `item.item.exception` is the expected variable name, always check that `item.item` is defined to avoid `has no attribute 'item'` before testing its `exception` key:

```
when: item.item is defined and item.item.exception is defined
```